# Como fazer consulta em várias colunas

Tags: php, pdo

Como posso consultar em várias colunas o valor igual ao campo usando o PDO

```
$PDO = db_connect();

$busca = $_POST['campo'];
$vbusca = array("%$busca%");

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM livro AS t WHERE nome LIKE ?';

$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($vbusca);
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: Já tentou tentou escrever o `like` para cada coluna que quer consultar?

Comment: Não causaria conflito com o execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode esquecer dos parâmetros em `$vbusca = array();`, para cada campo a mais, você precisa adicionar ao parâmetro. Se deseja buscar pelo mesmo conteúdo, por exemplo em título do livro ou o tipo do livro, então seria assim:

```
$PDO = db_connect();

$busca = $_POST['campo'];
$vbusca = array("%$busca%", "%$busca%");

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM livro WHERE nome LIKE ? OR tipo LIKE ?';

$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($vbusca);
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Answer (score 1):

Só acrescentar outros valores ao `WHERE` junto com `OR` ou `AND`

```
$PDO = db_connect();

$busca = $_POST['campo'];
$vbusca = array("%$busca%");

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM livro AS t WHERE coluna1 = ? or coluna2 = ?';

$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($vbusca);
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Porém sua pergunta não deixou claro o tipo de dado que você retorna e o que você está buscando. Você também poderia fazer uso do `IN` se for múltiplos valores.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM livro AS t WHERE coluna1 IN (valor1,valor2)';
```

Comment: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

Comment: Me retornou este erro